# DX11 HLSL Secondary Texture Coordinates Lost

Tags: delphi, shader, pascal, directx-11, hlsl

Been banging my head up against the wall with this for a while.  Despite the fact that I THINK I have a proper Vertex Format defined with D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC, no matter what I do, I can't see to read my TEXCOORD1 values from this shader.  To test this shader, I put random values into my second set of UV coordinates just to see if they were reaching the shader, but to my dismay, I haven't been able to find these random values anywhere.  I have also watched the data go into the mapped memory directly, and I am pretty sure the random values were there when they were mapped.

Here is the Shader code:

```
sampler ImageSampler: register(s0);
Texture2D <float4> ImageTexture: register(t0);
Texture2D <float4> ReflectionTexture: register(t1);
//Texture2D <float4> ReflectionMap: register(t0);

struct PS_IN
{
  float4 InPos: SV_POSITION;
  float2 InTex: TEXCOORD;
  float2 InRef: TEXCOORD1;
  float4 InCol: COLOR0;
};

float4 main(PS_IN input): SV_TARGET
{
  float4 res;
  float4 mul;
  float2 tcRef;

  float4 res1 = ImageTexture.Sample(ImageSampler, input.InTex) * input.InCol;
  float4 res2 = ReflectionTexture.Sample(ImageSampler, input.InRef+input.InTex);
  mul.r = 0.5;
  mul.g = 0.5;
  mul.b = 0.5;
  mul.a = 0.5;
  res = res1 + res2;
  res = res * mul;
  res.a = res1.a;

  res.r = input.InRef.x;//<-----should be filled with random stuff... not working
  res.b = input.InRef.y;//<-----should be filled with random stuff... not working

  return res;
}
```

Here is my D3D11_ELEMENT_DESC... (sorry it is in pascal, but I like pascal)

```
const
  CanvasVertexLayout: array[0..3] of D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC =
    ((SemanticName: 'POSITION';
    SemanticIndex: 0;
    Format: DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT;
    InputSlot: 0;
    AlignedByteOffset: 0;
    InputSlotClass: D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
    InstanceDataStepRate: 0),

    (SemanticName: 'TEXCOORD';
    SemanticIndex: 0;
    Format: DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT;
    InputSlot: 0;
    AlignedByteOffset: 8;
    InputSlotClass: D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
    InstanceDataStepRate: 0),

    (SemanticName: 'TEXCOORD';
    SemanticIndex: 1;
    Format: DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT;
    InputSlot: 0;
    AlignedByteOffset: 16;
    InputSlotClass: D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
    InstanceDataStepRate: 0),

    (SemanticName: 'COLOR';
    SemanticIndex: 0;
    Format: DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    InputSlot: 0;
    AlignedByteOffset: 24;
    InputSlotClass: D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
    InstanceDataStepRate: 0)
    );
```

And here's the Vertext Struct

```
TVertexEntry = packed record
  X, Y: Single;
  U, V: Single;
  u2,v2:single;
  Color: LongWord;
end;
```

Since the COLOR semantic follows the TEXTURE semantics, my best guess is that the problem is with the SHADER and not the pascal code... but since I'm new to this kind of stuff, I'm obviously lost

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious, why pack the vertex? Won't that misalign it?

Comment: I have tried it packed and unpacked.  It was originally unpacked.  In this case it should make a difference I think (although I should double check since I'm targeting Win64)

Comment: Just tried it packed AND unpacked... no difference, been mucking around with it trying to figure out if it was an alignment issue.  Also ran it Win32 and Win64 ... ran the same on both targets.

Comment: Why would mis-aligning help?

Comment: I should also note that everything draws MOSTLY okay, which tells me that the Vertex Sizes are properly aligned when they are mapped and transferred to the GPU.  But My u2 and v2 values, are generally 0ish and 1ish instead of random like I expect.

Comment: I don't think you understand what packed means. Anyway, as to the actual problem, surely we are missing code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan by testing it packed, I would have the ability to align it manually... that's all.. it would also simply tell me if there's an alignment issue.  If I misalign it and it all goes garbled, then I might know that there's something I can look at there... regardless, the use of the "packed" keyword has no effect in this situation, because everything is already 32-bit aligned.

Comment: OK, that confirms that you don't know what I mean. You are talking about layout within the struct. I am talking about the type's alignment. Which is 1 when packed. Surely not the real issue but such a common error from Delphi devs.

Comment: packed (1-byte) aligns it within the struct, yes... certainly I know what alignment is. And even if the structs weren't aligned, they get copied into a memory buffer allocated by DirectX, which is most certainly aligned. A "packed" array of 1-byte-aligned structs would be misaligned at each index (potentially) unless you ensure that the struct size is a padded... hence my comment about "packing" causing misalignment... with-in a packed array... yes they'd be misaligned... if not already multiples of 4-bytes in size.  I wasn't sure if the 64-bit compiler would align to 8 or 4-bytes is all

Comment: Alignment and layout are different things. Packed affects both. I'm talking about alignment. The layout is the same packed and aligned. I still don't understand why you would want to misalign.

Comment: it was a TEST to see if the problem was the alignment that the compiler used when placing the struct members... IF you've been in the business for 30 years, you've most certainly run into situations where the compiler aligned something on a boundary that you didn't expect either causing you to lose your value or even throwing an exception at the CPU level... it was a TEST to make sure the compiler was aligning the members as I thought it was.. THATS ALL

Comment: anyway I think I found it anyway... the reason that TEXCOORD1 would get  lost is because it was lost at the VertexShader level.  In upgrading the PixelShader to use 2 sets of UV coordinates, I also had to upgrade the VErtexShader.... testing this now..... unfortunately, this will be my first VertexShader

Comment: The thing is, it would fail when the struct was misaligned. Packed will misalign the struct, without packed the struct will be aligned. So if you are concerned that the struct is misaligned you would remove packed. You seem to think that packed will result in the struct being aligned.

Comment: by adding packed I wanted it to FAIL... and I only left it in because it didn't... I should have taken it back out.

Comment: OK. That's a classic. The question is asked with the messed around code.

Comment: I typically prefer to pad the struct myself anyway if I need to... again... made no difference, and NEVER would in this case.  I don't understand why you're harping on about packed and alignment.  The correct answer is below.

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer the question. I wanted to help you learn about alignment. Based on that last comment it seems that you still don't get it. Anyway, you don't want to listen to what I am saying which is fine.

Comment: If you're thinking of alignment for the purpose of SSE instructions which *should* be 16-byte aligned... that's really a different subject.  This code (obtained from a 3rd party) does not use SSE instructions (which I will fix later... totally OFF topic).  I don't like this Vertex Format he's put together, I am clearly in the process of changing it.  In Delphi you have to write your own asm code for dealing with SSE, which I have done, but not in this codebase that, again, came from a 3rd party.

Comment: Some processors will halt on maligned memory addresses.  I have 30 years experience working with C, C++, C#, Pascal and others.  I'd be in big trouble if I didn't know about memory alignment.  And yes, I know that SSE requires 16-byte alignment, but every AMD64 based processor supports SSE2 or better these days for which the penalties for misalignment are less severe.  Again... completely off topic.

Comment: You keep saying that you know what alignment is, but then making comments that suggest otherwise. You said, "by testing it packed, I would have the ability to align it manually". In Delphi, if you use packed, the structure has alignment 1. You can't align manually. So, unless you want a structure with alignment 1, don't use packed. That's all.

Comment: You have contributed nothing to this.  You ABSOLUTELY can align the structs manually if they are packed, by modifying the structs and adding padding bytes.  I do this ALL THE FRIGGEN TIME and YES it results in your struct members being aligned and has no affect on the base pointer of the struct.  For example if I have a struct with members {byte_t a; int16_t b } and want to 32-bit align them, you simply restructure it {byte_t a; byte_t unused[3]; int16_t b; int16_t unused2}   Magic!  Now A and B are aligned through the use of padded bytes.  Not an unusual technique assuming the base is aligned

Comment: `packed record I: integer` has size 4 and alignment 1. `record I: integer` has size 4 alignment 4. The former is not aligned, the latter is. The layout of both records is the same, the alignment differs. I don't think I am an idiot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.  Since I'm new to Shaders in general, maybe this will help some other newbs.

I was assuming that all I needed to do was add a second set of UV coordinates to the Vertex Format and add a D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC for it.  However, there is also a vertex shader involved, more-or-less a passthrough and that vertex shader needs to be aware of the new UV coordinates and let them pass through.  I was just making a 2D engine so I didn't think that I'd even have to mess with VertexShaders... go figure. So I modified the vertex shader, and this was the result:

```
void main(
  float2 InPos: POSITION0,
  float2 InTex: TEXCOORD0,
  float2 InTex2: TEXCOORD1,//<--added
  float4 InCol: COLOR0,
  out float4 OutPos: SV_POSITION,
  out float2 OutTex: TEXCOORD2,
  out float2 OutTex2: TEXCOORD3,//<--added
  out float4 OutCol: COLOR0)
{
  OutPos = float4(InPos, 0.0, 1.0);
  OutTex = InTex;
  OutCol = InCol;
  OutTex2 = InTex2;//<--added

}
```

Comment: I have used DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT format for a vertex position of 2D coordinate (x, y). My VS input is (float2 position : POSITION0). But ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader() throws: D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader: Shader must be vs_4_0, vs_4_1, or vs_5_0. Shader version provided: ps_4_0 [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #167: CREATEVERTEXSHADER_INVALIDSHADERTYPE]
D3D11: **BREAK** enabled for the previous message, which was: [ ERROR STATE_CREATION #167: CREATEVERTEXSHADER_INVALIDSHADERTYPE ]